# Drill not finding drillbit from zookeeper?

Tags: java, apache-drill

I am trying out the drill sample in my project using this example.

https://github.com/vicenteg/DrillJDBCExample/blob/master/src/main/java/com/mapr/drill/DrillJDBCExample.java

I have started drillbits on all my datanodes with the same "cluster-id" and I specify "zk.connect" to point to "zookeeper1,zookeeper2,zookeeper3" in my drill-override.conf (picked up by default i believe).

I am getting the following error:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: No DrillbitEndpoint can be found

Am I supposed to start drillbits on my zookeeper nodes too in addition to my datanodes? Or what is wrong?

My drill-override is as follows:

```
 drill.exec: {
  cluster-id: "testcluster",
  zk.connect: "zookeeper1:2181,zookeeper2:2181,zookeeper3:2181"
 }
```

Comment: Check if your datanodes (on which drillbits are started) can resolve zookeeper hostname.

Comment: Yes, they can resolve zookeeper hostname (from ping)

Comment: When I do a query for bits using a drill shell i start up (outside my java program), I can see that when using the zookeepers as part of connection string, all the data node bits" are running.

Comment: Let me rephrase, you tried `drill-localhost` & shell appeared and you tried querying from that shell (not JDBC) it's working. You got problem with JDBC java code?

Comment: drill-localhost was run on a separate linux machine (without any drillbit running). I am running my JDBC java code on a windows machine. I can ping the zookeepers from my windows machine.

Comment: try direct connection with drillbits to check set up working or not using  `jdbc:drill:drillbit=<node-name1>:2181,<node-name2>:2181,<node-name2>:2181`

Comment: Also, you should ask this question on drill's [mailing list](https://drill.apache.org/mailinglists/). Post query on: **user@drill.apache.org**. Drill's developers are active there.

Answer (score 0):

if you are trying to connect to a different machine where drill is installed. Then while connecting from windows, give ip address of the machine where drill is running as . 
**Important**
If in drill-override.conf(Linux machine where Drill is running) you have written "zookeeper1" as node name, then you should modify your "c:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts" file in your client machine, and gave a DNS name of that ip. 
Example : 
192.168.32.84 zookeeper1 .